# How to rename zpool vdev path

Tags: zfs

My pool is clean and working fine, but at creation time I used for some of the vdev, the device name instead of the label associated with the GPT table, and now I have

```
    NAME            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data            ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        da0p2       ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1p2       ONLINE       0     0     0
        gpt/data:3  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Instead of

```
    NAME            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data            ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        gpt/data:1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gpt/data:2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        gpt/data:3  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

That's only cosmetic, but I'd like to fix it.
Doing `zpool replace -f data da1p2 gpt/data:2` is not working:

```
invalid vdev specification
the following errors must be manually repaired:
/dev/gpt/data:2 is part of active pool 'data'
```

How to do it? Of course without complety destroying the vdev, and having to resilver the whole pool!

Is there a way to use zdb to edit the MOS configuration, and change it there?

```
data:
  vdev_tree:
    children[1]:
      path: '/dev/da1p2'
```

Comment: Export the zpool and reimport with `zpool import -d /dev/gpt`?

Comment: Check this thread to see if addresses your desire to convert the device name: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967091/zpool-degrades-when-plugging-in-a-drive